# Making a "Power Wall" battery out of cell phone batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, cellphone

Cellphone batteries varies in shape and size, and most importantly, in battery chemistries. Some chemistries result in a nominal voltage under load of 3.7 V with a full charge at 4.2 V (same as 18650), some operate at 3.8 V with a full charge of 4.35 V and some operate at a nominal 3.82 V with full charge 4.4 V.

Once the obstacles associated with working with inconsistent shapes and sizes and that of soldering the aluminum positive tabs to create parallel and series connections are overcome, is there any reason why, given the different nominal operating voltages of the cells, cellphone batteries cannot be combined to build a power wall in a similar way that 18650 cells are used for this purpose? The intention is to use a Daily 3.7 V 7S 40 A BMS for a 24 V battery build.

Am I correct in my assumption that the BMS will limit the total charge voltage to 4.2 V and keep all cells balanced just like it does for the 18650 cells? I suspect this may result in the cells with a higher nominal voltage to be charged to a maximum of 96% of their capacity, but that none of the cells will ever be over charged?

Comment: Reasons why this is likely a very bad idea: https://www.reddit.com/r/spicypillows/ Phone batteries aren't exactly reliable.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Thanks for reading the question. Everything has some risk. We navigate life and must use what is available to us as economically and efficiently possible. We are never more than approximately 20meters away from Li-ion batteries in some device and use such devices in close proximity to our bodies in conditions which is much higher risk than a stationary, permanently fixed, monitored battery placed in a temperature-controlled environment with safety protocols such as heat sensors and over current protection. For every risk there is some solution which mitigate that risk.

Comment: When one of these cheap phone batteries fails, it'll just puff up, discharge itself, and then be dead. However, when it's connected to a bunch of other batteries in a battery bank, those other batteries can keep pushing current into a defective cell long after the defective one discharged itself, setting it on fire. That's why these cells are safe-ish individually, but almost guaranteed to light on fire in a large battery bank. Phone batteries are just not designed for this application, and very unsafe when you use them like that.

Comment: Many devised such as laptops and power tools use these and 18650 cells in a 12V 2P 3S or even higher combination perfectly safely. I have seen a number of laptop cells using the same cell chemistries as offered in cell phones with one or two cells dead and bloated. Again, the heat protection offered by the BMS and thermal fuses must be capable of shutting the battery down in an overheat scenario just like the laptop battery BMS does in such event.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any reason why, given the different nominal operating voltages of the cells, cellphone batteries cannot be combined to build a power wall in a similar way that 18650 cells are used for this purpose?

There is: connecting protected Li-ion batteries in parallel is bad as it can at best degrade the cells and at worst damage the battery. This is why:

1. Battery A gets hot. Its BMS shuts it down. The SoC remains constant
2. Other batteries continue to operate. Their SoC (State of Charge) changes
3. Later, battery A cools down. Its BMS turns it back on. By now, its SoC is different from the other batteries because they remained in use
4. A huge inrush of current flows from the most charged batteries to the least charged ones

That inrush of current is too high for the cells being charged, leading to Lithium metal deposition on the negative electrode. At best, that reduces its capacity. At worst, it created dendrites that may cross the separator and start self heating, eventually leading to a thermal runaway.

> Am I correct in my assumption that the BMS will limit the total charge voltage to 4.2V and keep all cells balanced just like it does for the 18650 cells?

Yes, that is correct. However, it's doesn't *regulate* the voltage, it simply shuts down. You still need a charger to regulate the voltage and the current.

> that none of the cells will ever be over charged?

Correct: each BMS protects the cells in its own battery and prevents that.

EDIT:

The only safe way to make a "Power wall" (a large battery) from small batteries is to:

1. take the cells from the small batteries
2. make large blocks of cells *at the same voltage* connected directly and permanently in parallel
3. connect multiple such blocks in series to achieve the desired voltage
4. Buy a new BMS for that number of cells in series and that can handle the higher current
5. Install the BMS correctly, so that it is able to disconnect the entire battery current if it needs to to protect any cell in the battery
6. Realize that you spent more money and effort than buying a ready-made "power wall"-type battery

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response Davide. I agree that the factory fitted protection board must be removed for each cell. The question is if the voltage difference of unprotected phone cells in, for instance, a 28P 7S formation connected to a 40A 3.7V Daly BMS, exactly in the way described in your last paragraph, presents a risk.

Comment: The total cost is approximately US$46 for a 1KWH battery which decreases for larger capacity batteries. That is US$ 0.046/wh. I doubt that you will find a more cost effective li-ion solution. It does take some effort though. But no more than working with 18650 cells.

Comment: Don't forget that you'll have to add DC fuses to every single one of the cells. This drives up the cost dramatically; the fuses likely cost a lot more than the cells. (Individually fused cells are the only way to prevent a fire in case a single cell fails. All larger lithium battery banks have them.) Littelfuse's Pico series of fuses will add $0.50 per phone battery, for example. With 300 cells, that's already $150 just for fuses. The alternative is a guaranteed fire.

Comment: Adding a fuse per cell is the topic of hotly debated religious wars. I see you are on one side of that topic. But there is an equally vociferous school of though on the opposite side that says that a) It's a solution in search or a problem; b) fuses may actually reduce reliability. Tesla just switched sides (from your side to the no-fuse side).

Comment: Would you consider that if cells are connected in parallel with a fuse wire, (cut stem of a small resister), which burn off in the even that a cell exceed approximately 1amp to a nickel strip, which is done with most 18650 builds, mitigates the risk somewhat? Additionally, if the design allows for blocks of 5 cells to be connected to a nickel strip in parallel using such fuse wire and that such block of 5 cells is than fuse connected to a main high current conductor which is fuse connected individually to the other blocks in the parallel connection will offer sufficient fire protection?

Comment: "mitigates the risk somewhat? " Yes, but it also adds some other risks: that fusible link is in itself an additional potential source of ignition.  "will offer sufficient fire protection?" Fuses don't offer fire protection, no matter where they are placed. Fuses only protect against overcurrent. Overcurrent may or may not be a cause of fire, and fire may be caused by any of various causes, possibly including overcurrent.

Comment: Tesla isn't exactly building huge battery banks from unreliable and somewhat questionable used pouch cells, though. Tesla can calculate the risk of one cell shorting out and the damage it would cause, while it's totally unpredictable with used phone batteries, especially since they're all from different manufacturers and some will be more prone to failing short than others. Fuses are a must with such wacky cells. A "cut stem of a resistor" is definitely NOT a fuse. A proper fuse also won't be an ignition source when it blows (it's encapsulated after all). Ideally, you'd use thermal fuses.